# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to print a matrix of a size (m+1 X n+1) where m & n are lengths of two strings entered by the user. Why do I get an ArrayIndexOutofBounds Exception, when I print the matrix?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
public class Strings {

private static int alen ,blen;
int [][] matrix = new int[alen+1][blen+1];
public static void main(String[] args){

    Strings String1 = new Strings();
    String a,b;
    System.out.println("Enter String a: ");
    Scanner usrip = new Scanner(System.in);
    a = usrip.next();
    alen = a.length();
    System.out.println("Enter String b: ");
    b = usrip.next();
    blen = b.length();
    usrip.close();
    System.out.println("Matrix size:  " +  alen + "X" + blen );
    String1.printMatrix();
    /*System.out.println("Execute populate method: ");
    String1.populateMatrix();*/


}//end of main

public void printMatrix(){

    for(int i=0;i<alen+1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;i<blen+1;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
        }
        }
    }//end of printMatrix
```

Sample run:

```
Enter String a: 
apple
Enter String b: 

java
Matrix size:  5X4
0Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at Strings.printMatrix(Strings.java:38)
at Strings.main(Strings.java:25)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created your 2D array too early.  With this line:

```
int [][] matrix = new int[alen+1][blen+1];
```

`alen` and `blen` are still `0` (their default initial value), so you created a 1x1 matrix.

Don't create it until you have initialized `alen` and `blen` in `main`:

```
blen = b.length();
usrip.close();
// Now create it:
String1.matrix = new int[alen+1][blen+1];
System.out.println("Matrix size:  " +  alen + "X" + blen );
```

It would be cleaner to move such initialization logic to a constructor.  Such a constructor would take `alen` and `blen` as parameters and create the matrix there.

Additionally, this line looks incorrect, checking `i` when looping over `j`:

```
for(int j=0;i<blen+1;j++)
```

Try

```
for(int j=0;j<blen+1;j++)
```

Comment: Thanks, when I push the matrix initialization into main method to where you said, my mehtod does not recognize the object called matrix, it says "matrix cannot be resolved to a variable".

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an array of 0 length as the array is initialized before variables `alen` and `blen` have been read from the user.  Don't initialize your matrix until the end of your main method, that way you can initialize to the requested size.

```
//...
usrip.close();
System.out.println("Matrix size:  " +  alen + "X" + blen );
//initialize here.
int [][] matrix = new int[alen+1][blen+1];
String1.printMatrix();
```

Also you are iterating from 0 to the matrix width and height, +1. This means you're referencing an index that doesn't exist as arrays in java are zero-indexed. Meaning they start from 0, not from one. Just remove the +1 in your print matrix method.

```
public void printMatrix(){
    for(int i=0;i<alen;i++)
    {
       for(int j=0;i<blen;j++)
       {
           System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
       }
    }
}//end of printMatrix
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use :

```
for(int i=0;i<alen;i++)
```

And :

```
for(int j=0;i<blen;j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to allocate 'matrix' before the values of alen and blen have been established, so your allocated matrix is 1x1.

Answer (score 0):

This Should work as expected

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.File;
    public class stringclass {

    private static int alen ,blen;
    static int [][] matrix = new int[alen][blen];
    public static void main(String[] args){

      stringclass String1 = new stringclass();
      String a,b;
      System.out.println("Enter String a: ");
      Scanner usrip = new Scanner(System.in);

      a = usrip.next();
      alen = a.length();
      System.out.println("Enter String b: ");

      b = usrip.next();
      blen = b.length();
      usrip.close();
      System.out.println("Matrix size:  " +  alen + "X" + blen );
      String1.printMatrix(matrix);
     /*System.out.println("Execute populate method: ");
      String1.populateMatrix();*/


      }//end of main



   public void printMatrix(int[][] matrix){

               for(int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++)
    {
    for(int j=0;i<matrix[i].length;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
    }
    }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(int j=0;i<blen[i];j++){ statements }
insted of 
for(int j=0;i<blen;j++){ statements}
hope this will solve your problem
```